# SQL-C# ~ Adicionar Aluno se não estiver na turma

Tags: c#, sql, orientação-a-objetos

Bom dia, tenho o seguinte código abaixo:

```
public void AdicionarAlunoTurma(Adicionar_Alunos aluno)
    {
        List<string> parametros = new List<string>();
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
        parametros.Add(aluno.id.ToString());
        parametros.Add(aluno.nome);
        parametros.Add(aluno.turmaID.ToString());
        query.Append("insert into persons_turma (personsID, persons_turma, turmaID) values (@param1,@param2,@param3) ");
        SqlDynamic.Execute(db, query.ToString(), parametros.ToArray());
```

e os campos da tabela são esses.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu defini que personsID fosse único por que estava tendo problemas com duplicação. Como eu poderia estar adicionando o mesmo  aluno em outra turma? Eu tentei desenvolver um IF antes da query, fazendo com que o SQL ignorasse que ele fosse unico e adicionasse mesmo assim. porém nao consegui terminar essa logica.

Agradeço desde já a ajuda

Comment: Adicionando a coluna `turmaID` na composição da chave?

Comment: eu faria um select anteriormente, para verificar se o personId já existe quando se trata da turmaId tal, se o resultado for maior que 1 então o usuário já foi cadastrado naquela turma!

Comment: O personId nao pode ser unico, a tabela persons_turma é para fazer a relação de alunos com a turma, a tabela persons_turma deve ter apenas os campos PersonId (nao unico, chave estrangeira referenciando um PersonId da tabela Person) , TurmaId (nao unico, chavee estrangeira referenciando TurmaId da tabela Turma) e uma chave primaria PersonTurmaId, assim você garante que você faz a relação de pessoas existentes com turmas existentes e pode referenciar qualquer pessoa com qualquer turma

Comment: Provavelmente existe um problema de má definição da tabela e dos relacionamentos como dito pelo @JoãoPauloAmorim no comentário acima. Poste o comando de create da tabela persons_turma para podermos analisar melhor, eu até iria responder algo, mais o que parece que a definição das chaves e relacionamentos da tabela está com problemas.

Comment: eu nao salvei os codigos usados para a criação da tabela (criei ela tem uns 5 dias)

Comment: eu retirei esse comando dele ser UNICO. só necessitaria mesmo agora que ele fizesse uma varredura para verificar se o aluno já está naquela turma

Comment: @MatheusMuniz faça um select na tabela antes passando personId e TurmaId, se retornar registros você não salva.

Comment: @JoãoPauloAmorim eu fiz a alteração e fiz o seguinte codigo:

Answer (score 0):

Na cláusula `WHERE` você define na sua montagem o ID da turma que você quer listar.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM persons_turma 
 WHERE personsID = pessoaId 
   AND turmaID = turmaId
```

Answer (score 0):

Faça um `SELECT` para verificar se existe o aluno que deseja incluir a turma ja existe:

```
public int ExisteAluno(int idAluno) 
{
    string strQuery = "SELECT id FROM tabela WHERE personsID = @p_id";
    return db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(strQuery, new SqlParameter("@p_id", idAluno)).FirstOrDefault();
}

if(ExisteAluno(idAluno) == 0)
{
    // Insere o aluno na turma aqui!
}
```

**ATENÇÃO**: Plural de pessoa em ingles é **people**!